# JAVA using a loop to find the sum from 0 to x

Tags: java, loops, sum

I want to use a loop to find the sum of 0, to X. So if the user prints out 5 then the sum is 15.

```
int sum = 1;
for (int i=1; i<x; i++) {
    sum=sum+i;
}
System.out.println("The sum of 0 up to " + x + " is: " + sum );
```

Using this code above I've only been getting 11. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is x initialized?

Comment: Thats it! thank you so much!

Comment: And start sum with 0: sum=0

Comment: For completness: The sum of the first `n` integers is directly `n*(n+1)/2`, this would be the `O(1)` algorithm, as opposed to your `O(n)` algorithm. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

Comment: Comment above should be an answer

Answer (score 3):

Several errors in your code

1. initialize sum to 0
2. iterate from 1 to x, not from 1 to x - 1

   ```
   int x = 5;
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i=1; i<=x; i++)
   {
      sum = sum + i;
   }

   System.out.println("The sum of 0 up to " + x + " is: " + sum);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You should use your **for loop** like this :

```
for (int i=1; i<=x; i++) {
    sum=sum+i;
}
```

In addition to that if you need to improve the performance you can replace for loop which has O(n) time complexity with a single formula which has O(1) time complexity.

```
int x = 5;
int sum = x*(x+1)/2;
System.out.println("The sum of 0 up to " + x + " is: " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all set sum equals to 0 as you have nothing accumulated yet. Second of all you need to reach the last number so your iterator needs to be les or equals to number.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i=1; i<=x; i++)
{
   sum=sum+i;
}
System.out.println("The sum of 0 up to " +x+ " is: " +sum );
```